Database specific user in AWS Redshift
I've created 2 databases in Redshift engine:

database_production
database_development

Each database have 2 schemas: public and custom.
I want to create user called developer who has all privileges in database_development database but can't connect and modify any schema in database_production.
How to create developer users and grand/revoke desired permissions on database_development only?

You can use GRANT, you can check here how works grant. Following the documentation, the line to be executed would be:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_development TO developer


It will only grant CREATE | TEMPORARY | TEMP | ALTER privileges on the database, but doesn't prevent from querying other databases.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Connect to Redshift and create/grant user:
CREATE USER developer WITH PASSWORD 'testingtesitng';

#Grant access to database_development
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE database_development TO developer;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO developer;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA custom TO developer;

#Grant privileges on tables in the schemas
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO developer;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA custom TO developer;

#Grant privileges on sequences in the schemas
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO developer;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA custom TO developer;

Also you may double-check if this user can't access to database_production just try to connect to this DB and do smth there.
And revoke desired permissions:
# Revoke any access to database_production
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_production FROM developer;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE database_production FROM developer;
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA public FROM developer;
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA custom FROM developer;


There is no GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE or GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA commands in redshift.
